# Why is string concatenation not executed when using a field rather than an expression-bodied property?

Tags: c#, attributes, expression

Why does the following code outputs "STRING_PART_1\STRING_PART_2"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DummyClass.Property1);
    }
}

internal class DummyClass
{
    public static string Property1 => "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
    public static string Property2 => "STRING_PART_2";
}
```

But the following code outputs "STRING_PART_1" ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DummyClass.Property1);
    }
}

internal class DummyClass
{
    public static string Property1 = "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
    public static string Property2 = "STRING_PART_2";
}
```

What difference should I expect using an attribute (`=`) rather than an expression `=>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
public static string Property1 => "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
public static string Property1
{
    get => "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
}
```

So when you access this property the getter is called (which calls the getter of `Property2` inside).

These are not even properties - fields (not really matters in your case):

```
public static string Property1 = "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
public static string Property2 = "STRING_PART_2";
```

The initialization order is: `Property1` then `Property2`.

When you initialize `Property1` the `Property2` is not initialized yet (`null`) and this is the reason of your output.

When you change the declaration order to:

```
public static string Property2 = "STRING_PART_2";
public static string Property1 = "STRING_PART_1\\" + Property2;
```

you'll get desired result because `Property2` is initialized before `Property1`.

Comment: _When you initialize Property1 the Property2 is not initialized yet (null)_, although, if I write `string someString;string someOtherString = "hello" + someString;` I'll get a `Use of unassigned local variable 'someString'`. Why wouldn't I get this error with the declaration as fields ?

Comment: My understanding is that the compiler should throw the exact same error in both cases. However, it doesn't throw in the example I gave.

Comment: @ArthurAttout because field initializers have different "definite assignment" rules to local variables; if in doubt, use a constructor  (static in this case)

note: public fields, and (separately) mutable static fields are *usually* bad ideas

Comment: @ArthurAttout For me the IDE (Rider) shows a warning - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBTLl.png

Comment: @Roman good to know .. Too bad Visual Studio 2019 doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

When you switch `Property2` with `Property1` while using `=` it will output  `STRING_PART_1\STRING_PART_2`.

So the lambda expressions ignoring the order of the variables while the normal operations are not.